# tomcat 6 - update the catalina.out file location

Tags: tomcat, logging, catalina.out

I am working in a Linux server which comes with tomcat preinstalled(version 6) and we do not have admin access. I am trying to change the log file location(catalina.out), but it is not working.

I updated the tomcat6.conf file by adding the following

```
CATALINA_BASE="ORIG_LOC_FOLDER"
CATALINA_HOME="ORIG_LOC_FOLDER"
CATALINA_OUT="XXXX/catalina.out"
```

I restarted tomcat, but it still writes the logs to the old file in the old location. I could not change in the catalina.sh as I cannot find that file. Is there anything else I need to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The setting of `catalina.out` can be found in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties`.

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.
```

After copy and modify this file, you can override Tomcat's logging config file via this environment variable.

> LOGGING_CONFIG="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=$CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties"

### Update in 6/25

Another solution is changing `java.util.logging` configuration by program. Here is the sample code.

```
//import java.util.logging.*;
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("");
Handler[] ha = logger.getHandlers();
for (int i = 0; i < ha.length; i++) {
    logger.removeHandler(ha[i]);
    ha[i].close();
}
Handler fh = new FileHandler("%t/out.log");
fh.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
fh.setLevel (Level.FINE);
logger.addHandler (fh);
logger.setLevel (Level.FINE);
```

Comment: Thanks, will check tonight and get back.

Comment: Nope, even after setting this, it did not work, though I do see the settings in the ps -ef command. -Djava.util.logging.config.file=XXX/conf/logging.properties

Comment: Does the tomcat server start via $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh? The answer is come from descrption of that script. if environment variable `LOGGING_CONFIG` is specified, the default value will be replaced.

Comment: This is the default linux install and I assume it uses the file /etc/init.d/tomcat6 to start. I have view only access for this file and I checked there and did not find anything related to catalina.out. When we install tomcat, then it is easy to change, but with this I am not sure how to change the location. Thanks

Comment: `catalina.out` is writed by `java.util.logging`, you have to change the setting of `java.util.logging`. If your startup script similar to https://gist.github.com/FrankGrimm/1480319, you have to modify the line 134-142. So `LOGGING_CONFIG` could be exported to `catalina.sh`.

Comment: The script is similar, but not the same. I will try to update via code and check. Thanks